# IMvxPictureChooserTask not working on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

Have a problem with IMvxPictureChooserTask on Xamarin.iOS. When trying on the first time to TakePicture or ChoosePictureFromLibrary - nothing happen. All the next times in logs appear the message:

MvxImagePickerTask called when task already active

and nothing else.

So can some one help or suggest something?

**UPDATE 1**

Code that failing:

```
public HomeViewModel(IDataService dataService, IApiService apiService, IMvxPictureChooserTask pictureChooserTask)
{
    _apiService = apiService;
    _dataService = dataService;
    _pictureChooserTask = pictureChooserTask;

    //Another staff here
}

private void DoAddPicture()
{
    _pictureChooserTask.TakePicture(400, 95, OnPicture, () => { });
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

The problem is that I'm using custom presenter for side menu functionality. It inherited from MvxBaseTouchViewPresenter. MvxImagePickerTask  works fine without this.

So can someone suggest how can I use both MvxImagePickerTask and custom presenter? Or may be other suggestions how can I have both functionality with another solution based on MvvmCross.

**SOLUTION**

Just need to override PresentModalViewController in custom presenter:

```
public override bool PresentModalViewController(MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController viewController, bool animated)
{
    var currentViewController = _flyOutNavigationController.ViewControllers[_flyOutNavigationController.SelectedIndex] as UINavigationController;
    currentViewController.PresentViewController(viewController, true, null);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your code that is failing? Have you tried the samples or the N+1 videos as these show some sample use?

Comment: Yes, I've tried the samples from N+1 and from tutorial. And it works fine, but not in my project(

Comment: I found the problem. I'm using custom presenter inherited from MvxBaseTouchViewPresenter. So I'm tried with out and it works. Stuart can you suggest how I can use both? As I can not remove custom presenter from app at all, I'm using it for side menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Just need to override PresentModalViewController in custom presenter:

```
public override bool PresentModalViewController(MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController viewController, bool animated)
{
    var currentViewController = _flyOutNavigationController.ViewControllers[_flyOutNavigationController.SelectedIndex] as UINavigationController;
    currentViewController.PresentViewController(viewController, true, null);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue when using Xamarin.Forms (Cheesebarons / Ninjacoder) solution for integrating MvvmCross and Xamarin.Forms.

I was able to make it work using the following, however it seems like a hack. It does however only solve the issue for the *first* use of the `TakePicture` it does note in the debugging output:

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

Even though the first one returns with an image stream, any subsequent calls will not return, and after the second call to `TakePicture` call will show

> mvx:Warning: 30,97 MvxImagePickerTask called when task already active

My solution is:

```cs
public virtual bool PresentModalViewController(UIViewController controller, bool animated) {
        _window.RootViewController.PresentViewController(controller, true, null);
}
```

**UPDATE: Some sort of resolution**

Before the `IMvxPictureChooserTask` was instantiated in the ViewModel `ctor` by MvvmCross automatically.

I solved it for subsequent calls to `TakePicture` by resolving the task every time using `Mvx.Resolve()`

Before:

```cs
private IMvxPictureChooserTask globalTask;

private void Snapshot() {
    var stream = await globalTask.TakePicture(1200, 95);
    // Would only come here on the first attempt
}

public MainViewModel(IMvxPictureChooserTask task) {
    globalTask = task;
}
```

Solution:

```cs
private void Snapshot() {
    var task = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxPictureChooserTask>();
    var stream = await task.TakePicture(1200, 95);
    // works everytime
}
```

I am a little worried that there is a memory leak in there somewhere.

Comment: I solved it for subsequent calls to `TakePicture` by resolving the task every time using `Mvx.Resolve()` (see edit above)